# what is the relation of this two tables?

Tags: php

items table

```
    protected static $_properties = array(
    'id',
    'product_code',
    'item_color_id',
    'item_size_type_id',
    'classification_id',
    'name',
    'display_name',
    'usual_price',
    'selling_price',
    'point_ratio',
    'description',
    'publish_start_datetime',
    'publish_end_datetime',
    'publish_flag',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
);
```

images table:

```
    protected static $_properties = array(
    'id',
    'file_name',
    'content_type',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
);
```

item_image table:

```
    protected static $_properties = array(
    'id',
    'item_id',
    'image_id',
    'type',
    'view_order'
);
```

why it needs a item_image table? what's the relationship of item and image? many to many or one to many?
and the question is when I insert into image tables there is no error,but if i delete from image table there will be an error (foreign key issue). Why should this happen? How to delete image from the tables.

Comment: I assume it's so images can be on multiple items, or items can have multiple images. But with no context, there's no way to answer this.

Comment: @yaosuzhou I suggest you first slow down and take a deep breath. Googlin many to many relationship will most certainly help you understand wether this is or not such a relation. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you ask better questions, as this may help you getting answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this kind of setup is to have a many-to-many relationship between `items` and `images`. `item_image` allows you to setup relationships between any `item` and any `image`, any number of times. You're having trouble deleting from the `image` table because it is related to a row in the `item_image` table. You first have to delete any relationships in `item_image` that include that image, and then delete the row from the `image` table.

The database is setup this way so that your relationships don't become outdated or orphaned. If you delete a row from the `image` table, but leave a row in `item_image` that relates to the deleted row, then then relationship will point at nothing and could cause issues.

This is assuming that this is a typical many-to-many relationship, if you don't know the structure of the database, you should talk to the person who made it before making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. according to database this could be a many to many relation as an `item_image` table is created between `items` and `images`.

So if you want to delete an item from the image table then first you have to check if the `id` for both `image` and `item` is stored in `item_image`. if it exists then you can delete your image where `id` in `image` table = `image_id` from your `image_item`